# redirect posts to new address

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've change permalink of my wordpress site from

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

to

```
%postname%
```

I've tested this code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ site.com/$4
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ site.com/$3
```

and good work for redirect posts but this code redirect categories address too and show 404 not found page.

I need to only redirect old posts address to new address.
Is it possible that only the posts be redirect?

Example:

```
site.com\cat1\subcat\post
redirect to:
site.com\post (no problem)
```

my site Categories in two or three level

two level not have problem but three level:

```
site.com\cat1\subcat\subcat2
(Categories should not be redirect)
but redirect to:
site.com\subcat2 (and Error 404 Not Found)
```

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Please post a couple of examples of the urls for the category addresses which produce the 404 errors and a couple of the posts which are being successfully redirected..

Comment: site.com/cat1/subcat/subcat2 match the second rules and redirect to site.com/$3 the site.com/subcat2.
an url like site.com/cat1/subcat/subcat2/postname must match site.com/$4 and redirect to site.com/postname

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with PHP.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301); 
}
```